# Getting an error when trying to use a POST request from a Python script

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, python-requests

I want to send a POST request to a website to get a download link, but when I do, it responds with:
`{"status":"ok","c_status":"FAILED","mess":"An error has occurred. Please try again! "}`

When I resend the request from the inspect tab of Firefox it responds with:

```
{"status":"ok","mess":"","c_status":"CONVERTED","vid":"F_HoMkkRHv8","title":"Cake - The Distance (Official Video)","ftype":"mp3","fquality":"128","dlink":"https:\/\/dl143.y2mate.com\/?file=M3R4SUNiN3JsOHJ6WWQ3aTdPRFA4NW1rRVJIOGxQSXZuWjV4OHhnbVNvOUZ0Wmt1MmVlbGFPWkpLSzRNeEl1dVd1aGQ4VHZYUDkyYlkwbVB2NVFqZldPQTQ5NWcvRzNwNm9FMVRkeHpVMU9xdmV1enhYUWtyMUt3TFA3cktwQlpRSHh3a1doMWkyaWUzS0tTdmhEMzdsNk00VWliZkMwWXR5OENNUENOb01rZWpUdVNOcWV4ZzlZV3UzdWI0TTg9"}
```

Which is what I want to get with my script

I'm not sure whether it needs headers or not so I've tried with and without adding headers but neither changed anything.
If anyone can tell what I'm doing wrong/misunderstanding that would be greatly appreciated

```
import requests 

url = "http://yt1s.com/api/ajaxConvert/convert"

header = {
"Host": "yt1s.com",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"Content-Length": "94",
"Origin": "null",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
"Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Cookie": "_ga=GA1.2.1571820535.1667494818; _gid=GA1.2.1382638961.1668295256; prefetchAd_3897490=true; prefetchAd_4425332=true; AdskeeperStorage=%7B%220%22%3A%7B%22svspr%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fyt1s.com%2Fen422%22%2C%22svsds%22%3A1%7D%2C%22C1351947%22%3A%7B%22page%22%3A1%2C%22time%22%3A1668295270300%7D%7D",
}

data = 'vid=F_HoMkkRHv8&k=0%2Be9UUPRJ7ryRtXVXps4nRRiPRF1HVSf5l7v3sVU68OOkTWDWvLn%2FHeNOCGBh7Z%2B3Xo%3D'


r = requests.post(url, headers= header, data = data)

print (r.text)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write(str(r.text))
```

Comment: The error is created by the server. It is impossible to know what logic it has. Possibly some authentication or session info is missing.

Comment: Unsure but has the service been discontinued as of August 1, 2021 (when you load the base URL into a browser that is the message that you get), so unsure if the API is available.